# How to properly Join my tables?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have these tables in my database. I want to Select all available rooms in the check-in date 2016-24-09 and check-out date 2016-26-09.

**guest table**

```
.---------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------.
| guestID | Guest Name   |  check_in  | check_out  | date_created |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|   1     | Guest 1 Name | 2016-27-09 | 2016-29-09 | 2016-10-09   |
|   2     | Guest 2 Name | 2016-30-09 | 2016-31-09 | 2016-04-09   |
.---------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------.
```

**rooms table**

```
.---------+-----------------+-----------.
| RoomID  | RoomDetailsNo   |room_status|
+---------+-----------------+-----------
|   101   |         1       | reserved  |
|   102   |         3       | available |
|   103   |         3       | available |
|   104   |         2       | reserved  |
|   105   |         2       | available |
|   106   |         1       | available |
.---------+-----------------+-----------.
```

**roomdetails table **

```
.----------------+---------------+---------.
| RoomDetailsNo  |   room_type   |room_rate|
+----------------+---------------+---------+
|        1       | Standard Room |  3000   |
|        2       | Deluxe Room   |  3500   |
|        3       | Luxury Room   |  4000   |
.---------+-----------------+--------------.
```

**roomreservation table**

```
.---------------+---------+--------.
| reservationID | guestID | roomNo |
+---------------+---------+--------+
|       1       |    1    |   101  |
|       2       |    2    |   104  |
.---------+--------------+---------.
```

I used this query

```
SELECT COUNT(r.roomDetailsNo) AS available_rooms, rd.roomDetailsNo, rd.room_type, rd.room_rate, 
                                        r.room_status, rd.room_pax, rd.max_cap, rd.inclusive, rd.description, g.check_in, g.check_out,
                                        rr.guestID, rr.roomNo
                                    FROM rooms AS r
                                    LEFT JOIN roomdetails AS rd
                                    ON r.roomDetailsNo = rd.roomDetailsNo
                                    LEFT JOIN roomreservation AS rr
                                    ON rr.roomNo = r.roomNo
                                    LEFT JOIN guestandreservation AS g
                                    ON rr.guestID = g.guestID
                                    WHERE r.room_status = 'available' OR (g.check_in > $new_checkOut AND g.check_in > $new_checkIn AND r.room_status = 'reserved')
                                        OR (g.check_out > $new_checkIn AND g.check_out > $new_checkOut AND r.room_status = 'reserved')
                                    GROUP BY room_type;
```

Suppose I am a new guest who will make reservation and those rooms 101 are available till 2016-27-09 and 104 till 2016-30-09 and I'm booking from 2016-24-09 to 2016-26-09. how can I include those reserved rooms as available for reservation if they are still available in my check-in and check-out date? I don't know if my WHERE statement is wrong or my JOIN Statements

EDIT: I did not include it date created row at first because I thought it was unnecessary but the Guest table actually has date_created table

Comment: This database structure will not work well if the same guest comes back to reserve a room again. Suppose he got room 100 for 1 September, and room 101 for 10 September, how will you know whether room 101 is free on 1 September with this model? I would suggest to review your DB model first.

Comment: Note also that the second checkout date is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start tabulating the rooms being assigned. A room to be assigned **must*** have a reservation and it **must** have a guest, so simple JOINs:

```
SELECT r.RoomID, rr.check_in, rr.check_out
FROM rooms AS r
JOIN roomreservation AS rr ON (r.RoomID = rr.roomNo)
JOIN guests AS g ON (rr.guestID = g.guestID);
```

Now we want to check the rooms that are NOT free during a period (date1, date2). This means that we will find a room where date2 >= check_in, and date1 <= check_out. If this room had date2 < check_in, the room would not yet be busy; if date1 > check_out, the room would already have been vacated:

```
        c/i             c/o
---------|---------------|------------
 d1...d2
 d1............d2                      
             d1.......d2
             d1..............d2
                             d1....d2
```

So the rooms NOT free are

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.RoomID
FROM rooms AS r
JOIN roomreservation AS rr ON (r.RoomID = rr.roomNo)
JOIN guests AS g ON (rr.guestID = g.guestID)
WHERE date2 >= check_in AND date1 <= check_out;
```

Now we want the rooms that ARE free. These are the rooms which, joined to the above, *fail* the join. We then need a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT rf.* FROM rooms AS rf
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT r.RoomID
   FROM rooms AS r
   JOIN roomreservation AS rr ON (r.RoomID = rr.roomNo)
   JOIN guests AS g ON (rr.guestID = g.guestID)
   WHERE date2 >= check_in AND date1 <= check_out;
) AS rb ON (rf.RoomID = rb.RoomID)
WHERE rb.RoomID IS NULL;
```

Note: it is important that each guest have only one checkin/checkout, so this is good:

```
GuestID    Name             CI      CO
1          Mario Rossi      12/9    12/15
2          Mario Rossi      12/20   12/25
```

but this would be bad:

```
GuestID    Name             CI      CO
1          Mario Rossi      12/9    12/15
1          Mario Rossi      12/20   12/25
^---
```

Perhaps you might be better served by using a further table to store the guest's details, or better still, move checkin and checkout to the reservation table.

Comment: My primary keys are Auto_incremented so I won't have a problem with duplicated GuestID

Comment: @chemical_elii, it still is bad DB design to give the same physical person a different ID every time they come to reserve a room. That way *GuestID* is more a *ReservationID* than an ID of the guest. And in that case you might as well forget about the *roomreservation* table and store the *roomNo* directly in the *guest* table (which really is not that).

Comment: So how should I separate it? This is the first database I constructed it went through many alterations. I'm not sure how to do it really

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a guestTable(where guest details are stored) and a reservationTable(where all reservations are stored) so if the guest who had made reservation before will make a reservation the program will track his old guestID and place it in the new reservation he made?

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not fully understand the meaning of room_status field in the rooms table. There is no date range associated with this status flag, so it is hard to interpret what it means without any background information. So, I'm not touching your code regarding this field in the where clause.
2. Your table structure does not seem to make sense. You are storing the check in and out dates in the guests table, not in the reservation table. What if the same guest wants to make more than 1 reservation at the same time? Are you going to record the same guest under different guest id? What if the same guest wants to return and make a subsequent reservation? Do you want to loose your valuable historical data of your guests?
3. First you have to determine which rooms are not available for the proposed booking period and subtract this list from all rooms

`SELECT r.RoomId, rd.room_type, rd.room_rate, r.room_status
   FROM (rooms AS r INNER JOIN roomdetails AS rd) ON r.roomDetailsNo = rd.roomDetailsNo --I would not expect to have rooms without an appropriate roomdetails record
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT rr.roomNo
                   FROM roomreservation AS rr 
                   LEFT JOIN guestandreservation AS g ON rr.guestID = g.guestID
                   WHERE 
                        r.room_status = 'reserved' --I'm not touching this condition and this condition applies to all following conditions
                        AND ((g.check_in between $out AND $in)  --existing checkin overlaps
                             OR (g.check_out between $in AND $out)  -existing checkout overlaps
                             OR (g.check_in$out)) -- existing reservation is within the proposed booking range
                     ) as reserved ON reserved.roomNo = r.roomNo  --end of subquery, join condition to outer query
        WHERE reserved.roomNo is null --there is no reservation for the given roomNo`

You can use the above query as a subquery and get the number of available rooms by room type. I removed the fields from the query that are not available in the sample data you provided.

The reason for determining which rooms are reserved within the period first instead of determining which are available, is that a query can only evaluate if a particular booking for a room overlaps with the proposed booking, but cannot tell if there are no other existing bookings on a room that would eliminate that given room from the list of available rooms.

Comment: the room_status shows if the room is available/reserved/occupied on that day.

Comment: Which day does it apply to?

Comment: it's supposed to be applied on the check-in and check-out date of the guest and the status today of the room because we are also connecting it to our admin panel

Comment: I'm sorry, but without a data range, that field is meaningless.

Comment: can you help me? how do I do that data range stuff? I really know very few about mysql :(

Comment: or maybe set the duration when the room is available, reserved or occupied?

Comment: The reservations tell you when a room is reserved. If the guest checks in, then it is occupied, until checkout. The only thing you need to take care of 'administrative occupation', when a room is not available because of repairs, makeovers, etc, that have nothing to do with guest reservations. How you handle these things is up to you. These things have nothing really to do with mysql or sql, these should be part of your design. I do not know if this is a real life situation or a homework (I hope this is the latter), but sy has to think through the business requirements before coding.

Comment: i know this question dated few days ago but i really did not get th `(g.check_in$out))` part?